# Powershell Create Azure user with Microsoft Graph API

Tags: azure, powershell, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to create an Azure AD user using MS Graph api.  I followed the tutorial below.

https://scripting.up-in-the.cloud/powershell/how-to-use-graph-with-powershell.html

I am able to query other users I have created without any issues.  My permissions are all correct with being able to write to Azure AD.

When I run the code I keep getting Status code 400 bad reqeust.

I even tried with just his default usr settings and still fails with error 400.

```
  $usr = @{
"userPrincipalName"="Yannik@up-in-the.cloud"
"displayName"="Yannik"
"mailNickname"="Yannik"
"accountEnabled"="true"
"passwordProfile"= @{
    "forceChangePasswordNextSignIn" = "false"
    "forceChangePasswordNextSignInWithMfa" = "false"
    "password"="P@ssw0rd"
}
  } | ConvertTo-Json
```

Any idea what could be wrong with this request?

Comment: 400 error usually means an invalid value is sent. What you could do is parse the response body to see what's the error message is being sent by the API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The password must satisfy minimum requirements as specified by the user’s passwordPolicies property. By default, a strong password is required.  Can you attempt to modify the sample code with a known-good password for your org?

UPDATE:

I was able to get this code to work in my environment.  Please note you have to chane the UPN to match your tenant.  Also, I changed the booleans to `$true` and `$false`.

```
$usr = @{
"userPrincipalName"="Yannik@onehundred.onmicrosoft.com"
"displayName"="Yannik"
"mailNickname"="Yannik"
"accountEnabled"=$true
"passwordProfile"= @{
    "forceChangePasswordNextSignIn" = $false
    "forceChangePasswordNextSignInWithMfa" = $false
    "password"="P@ssw0rd123!"
}
  } | ConvertTo-Json
```

[image: Result of user create]

Comment: I did, i made a complex one.  The UI accepts it when I do via the ui.  I tried Jayden1234~$A.  UI allows it.

Comment: So it's still broken :(

Comment: see updates above.  I can get this to work in my instance.

Comment: Thank you so much.  it worked!!!